# ThemeableBrowser within ThemeableBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I need to open some links within ThemeableBrowser [link here](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser).

I have the following codes to call the ThemeableBrowser.

```
var options = {
                toolbar: {
                    height: 44,
                    color: '#cdcdcd'
              },
                title: {
                    color: '#003264ff',
                    showPageTitle: true
              },
                closeButton: {
                    image: 'close',
                    imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'closePressed'
              },
                backButton: {
                    image: 'back',
                    imagePressed: 'back_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'backPressed'
              },
                forwardButton: {
                    image: 'forward',
                    imagePressed: 'forward_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'forwardPressed'
              },
                closeButton: {
                    image: 'close',
                    imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'closePressed'
              },
                menu: {
                    image: 'menu',
                    imagePressed: 'menu_pressed',
                    title: 'Select for quick menu',
                    cancel: 'Cancel',
                    align: 'right',
                    items: [
                             {
                               event: 'btn1Pressed',
                               label: 'Button1'
                             },
                             {
                               event: 'btn2Pressed',
                               label: 'Button2'
                             }
                 };


function openBrowser(url) {
    cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open(host+url, '_blank', options)
    .addEventListener("btn1Pressed", function(e) {
                  //alert("btn1Pressed");
                  cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", options);
                  })
    .addEventListener("btn2Pressed", function(e) {
                  //alert("btn2Pressed");
                  cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "_blank", options);
                  });  
}
```

So, there are some items within the menu which is tappable and on each items, an even is registered. Now, when the item (example Button1) is pressed, it works for the first time but after that it does not work.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to resolve this issue.I just needed to call the same method(openBrowser()) within that function like this:

```
function openBrowser(url) {
    cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open(host+url, '_blank', options)
    .addEventListener("btn1Pressed", function(e) {
      // Call the same openBrowser("someDynamicURL") from here
      // Can not call cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open(url, '', {}) from here, I don't know why
        openBrowser("new dynamic URL");
    })
}
```